# ArrayList clearing itself in every iteration

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

I´ve been practicing inheritance through and abstract class, but I am having quite some trouble using the constructor and an ArrayList.

Everytime I consult all my info that was added to my Arraylist, they seem to only print the last added element this is what I got so far...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
do{
switch(menu){
case 1:
int x=//random generated number;
String name=//insert name;
reception add=new Reception(x,name);continue;


Public class reception extends Hotel{
public Reception(int number,String name,){
super(number,name);
}

import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract class Hotel {
    ArrayList<Integer> numerodehotel = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> residente1 = new ArrayList<String>();


    public Hotel(int number, String resident){
    this.resident1.add(resident);
    this.hotelroomnumber.add(number);
    }
```

Everytime I try to print all the elements they only seem to show the last added elements in both ArrayList, almost like is reseting itself in every iteration.

In the main class there is a switch with a do while that my idea was it should add all input elements without resseting and be able to consult them all

Comment: Could you please at least post some code that *compiles*?

Comment: is it normal to put continue instead of break; in switch ? with continue you create a while(true) loop, it's normal that nothirg appnes after that

Comment: Please format this illegible mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a new reception's object on every cycle iteration. Try to put this definition before the cycle and use this object in the cycle. Also, you'll need to write an empty constructor and getters/setters for values:

```
reception add=new Reception();
do {
    ...
    add.setNumerodehotel(x);
    add.setResidente1(name);
} while (...)

public abstract class Hotel {
    ArrayList<Integer> numerodehotel = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> residente1 = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Hotel(){
    }

    public void setNumerodehotel(int number){
       this.hotelroomnumber.add(number);
    }

    public void setResidente1(String resident){
       this.resident1.add(resident);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The flaw is within your constructor of the `Hotel` class. You are defining the `ArrayLists` at construction of the `Hotel` class

```
public abstract class Hotel {
    // Every time you create a new Hotel these two lines are executed
    ArrayList<Integer> numerodehotel = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> residente1 = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Hotel(int number, String resident){
        this.resident1.add(resident);
        this.hotelroomnumber.add(number);
    }
}
```

This is similar to doing this

```
public abstract class Hotel {
    ArrayList<Integer> numerodehotel;
    ArrayList<String> residente1;

    public Hotel(int number, String resident){
        numerodehotel = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        residente1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.resident1.add(resident);
        this.hotelroomnumber.add(number);

    }
}
```

So as you can see, every time you create a `Reception` (a new `Hotel`), a new ArrayList is created and then only one item will ever exist within your `ArrayLists`

You will probably just want to remove the adding from the constructor and add via a separate method.